# When is it ok to have both static and instance methods all in a class

Tags: ruby

This is not specific to Ruby, but I happen to be using Ruby at the moment.
Here is a class that provides text printing functionality.

```
class Printer

  # some static methods

  def self.fancy_print(text)
     # do fancy formatting
  end

  def self.print(text)
     fancy_print(text)
  end

  # some instance methods

  def initialize(text)
    @text = text
  end

  def print
    #somehow call fancy_print(@text)
  end
end
```

Is it bad design to provide both instance and static methods in a class?

Sometimes I would like to keep several instances of `Printer` lying around. Other times, I just need to say `Printer.print(text)` and just grab that text without bothering to store it for later, hence resulting in a static `print` method and an instance `print` method.

Comment: What would be the alternative? Provide a separate class just for static methods, and another one for non-static ones? That would be much more confusing

Comment: to answer the question embedded in your code: `self.class.fancy_print(@text)`

Comment: In Ruby, "static" methods are simply called class methods because they are defined on the class directly. They're actually a form of instance method on the class itself, because *everything* in Ruby is an instance of some kind of object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not bad design.

It's completely normal–some methods are class methods, some are instance methods. I'm not sure what the perceived issue might even be. It's somewhat difficult to even find classes with *only* one or the other, although in Java you frequently see static utility classes.

*Edit* IMO the question is misleading; you're actually asking if it's bad design to have static and instance methods *of the same name*.

It's tricky if both are public because it isn't necessarily obvious how to *use* the class. In other words, is it designed to be used via the static, or instance method? Both? What's different about them? Should that difference be... differentiated by a name?

Ultimately it depends on context and usage–there's no single answer.

Comment: I think the asker was specifically concerned about having class methods and instance methods *of the same name*.

Comment: hint hint modules and module_function

Comment: @DarshanComputing Oh; I guess that *is* embedded in the last paragraph, as opposed to the question "Is it bad design to provide both instance and static methods in a class." Missed the second part.

Comment: Not necessarily the same name, but both methods are basically doing the same thing. One might even be calling the other just to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: @Keikoku IMO it still depends on context; the class method could be a convenience method, while the instance method allows more-detailed configuration, options, manipulation, etc. If they do the *precise* same thing and a user would only *need* to use one or the other, then providing both is at least somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 5):

That's okay, I think. Here's how you would code the Printer#print method

```
class Printer
  def print
    self.class.fancy_print(@text)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know how to call class methods from an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with having class methods and instance methods for a specific class, as long as they make sense belonging to the class.

I.e. what does fancy_print do? Is it something specific to the Printer class. If it is, then you shouldn't worry.

On the other hand, if it is to be used for any string value, you can do something cheekier, i.e. adding this method to the string class

```
String.class_eval do 
  def fancy_print
    ## implementation
  end
end
```

Now you can do `"Hello".fancy_print`

Hope this answer was of any use. Also write test cases!

Comment: `String.class_eval do` is just plain confusing and is no better than `class String`. Even better would be to make a `module` and then `extend` the target class with it.